# Having trouble port forwarding for a specific game

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding

I have a F@st Sagemcom 5260 router. I am trying to port forward for the Game Unturned. The problem is that I have no clue what port to put into the 'External Port' box. Is there any way I can set it to accept all ports? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it forward all ports but that would be a very bad idea because it will essentially open up your computer to everyone on the outside unless you plan on blocking all the unused ports on your computer.  Do a Google search for "Unturned port forwarding" and you'll be able to see what ports have to be forwarded on one of the sites. If you're able to, forward both TCP and UDP ports because it's easier than doing trial-and-error to figure out which one you need.